# flask im trying to add a place holder and a required

Tags: python, mysql, flask

im trying to add a place holder and a required in register form

```
                <div class="form-group">
                <label>id</label>
                {{render_field(form.id_number, required, placeholder="enter id", class_ = "form-control")}}
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a validator, you can require an entry for a field. The associated HTML attribute is set automatically. The placeholder can also be specified within the definition of the form.

Your details on the form are very sparse. The example should nevertheless make the procedure clear to you.

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import IntegerField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired 

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    
    # ...
    
    id_number = IntegerField(
        'ID',
        validators=[
            DataRequired()
        ],
        description='ID Number',
        render_kw={
            'placeholder': 'Enter ID',
            'aria-discribedby': 'ID',
        }
    )
    
    # ...
```